# download for specific user in phoca download

Tags: joomla, download

Im trying to make a download section in which i want to give permissions to certain users to download certain files, for example:

I got two categories: - photos and files

I want richard download photos but not files, and the same with eric who want to download photos and files.

Comment: Are you looking to make an extension or are you looking to install one on Joomla?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with Phoca Download:

http://www.phoca.cz/documents/17-phoca-download-component/366-access-rights

> You can set access rights for category and for the file.
>
> Category Access Rights
>
> In category you can set that files in the category can
> be downloaded by registered users only. But you can set that such
> files can be downloaded by only one selected user too. Specific user
> can be selected in Category Edit mode. Then all files from the
> category can be download by only selected user(s).
>
> File Access Rights
>
> You can allow downloading files only for registered users.
> Such files can be displayed for all users or only for registered
> users. If they will be displayed for all users, public users can see
> them but they cannot download them. Only registered users can download
> them.
>
> Go to Components » Phoca Download » Files. Create new item or edit
> some existing item. Set Access level to e.g. Registered and set
> Display Unaccessible File to Yes. Now all users can see the file but
> only registered can download it.
>
> The difference to Categories rights is, in Category you can select
> specific user, not only the whole group (registered, special).

You can assign access rights for different users for evere category.